# NullPointerException when trying to submit a query

Tags: java

I am trying to execute java program but it seems the current code is returning null pointer exception on this piece of code:

```
IntegerDesc yearOfBuildDesc = 
     (IntegerDesc) myConcept.getAllAttributeDescs().get("yearOfBuild");
try {
    query.addAttribute(yearOfBuildDesc,
        yearOfBuildDesc.getAttribute("yearOfBuild"));
}
catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Do you know where the problem might come from?

Comment: On which line?  What did the debugger tell you?

Comment: NPE = something is not initialized or returns `null`. What can be not initialized in your code ? > only `myConcept` or `query` or one of your methods returns `null`

Comment: Post stack trace, and tell us what is exact line where you have NPE.

Answer (score 2):

Probably one of the following:

- `myConcept` is `null`, so `.getAllAttributeDescs()` falls over.
- `myConcept.getAllAttributeDescs()` returns `null`, so `.get("yearOfBuild")` falls over.
- `myConcept.getAllAttributeDescs().get("yearOfBuild")` returns `null`, leading `yearOfBuildDesc` to be `null` when you call `getAttribute` on it, which causes an exception.
- `query` is `null`, causing `.addAttribute(...)` to fall over.
- Something inside the `getAllAttributeDescs` method causes a null pointer exception when invoked.
- Something inside the `get` method causes a null pointer exception when invoked.
- Something inside the `addAttribute` method causes a null pointer exception when invoked.
- Something inside the `getAttribute` method causes a null pointer exception when invoked.
- Your initial code throws a `ParseException`, the call to whose `printStackTrace` method then throws a null pointer exception (unlikely).

In general, when hunting down null pointer exceptions, you should look for problems with:

- Select expressions (i.e. `x.y`) - can the `x` be `null`?
- Method calls - can the method throw a null pointer exception?

I've excluded the possibility that `e` is `null` here, since it's the exception you just caught.

Answer (score 0):

`yearOfBuildDesc` might be null. Test before using it in the try catch

`myConcept` might also be null, check also.

Answer (score 0):

```
yearOfBuildDesc.getAttribute("yearOfBuild");
```

Above line will throw `NullPointerException` if `yearOfBuildDesc` is null, add a null check.